# Why Order() in R don't return the correct order?

Tags: r, function

- I run these simple code in R and I don't know why it doesn't return the correct order.

order(c(4,1,4,3,2))

order(c("R","C","R","I","J"))

- This is the results:

[1] 2 5 4 1 3

[1] 2 4 5 1 3

- What is the problem?

Comment: `order()` returns the indexes of the values. Try `sort()` instead. `sort(c(4,1,4,3,2))` and 
`sort(c("R","C","R","I","J"))`.

Comment: What return value were you expecting?

Comment: Thank you, I found the answer, I mistook between order() and rank().

Answer (score 2):

The function `order()` returns the id (location) of the sorted elements. You could use:

```
v1 <- c(4,1,4,3,2)
v2 <- c("R","C","R","I","J")

sort(v1)
sort(v2)

#or

v1 <- v1[order(v1)]
v2 <- v2[order(v2)]
```